# Server setup for multi-site development web server with multiple contractors logging in?

Tags: server, apache2

While I've been using Linux for many years as a desktop OS I'm still a novice at the more serious server admin stuff. Basically I'm looking for a best practices that covers:

Hosting many domains (I'm doing this now, but I just muddled though without really knowing what I was doing, if there's a "right" way to do this I doubt I'm doing it)

Granting access to outsiders without letting them access all websites, just the ones they are working on. (I have been trying to use facl but the mask keeps getting reset, so the contractors keep losing write permissions to directories, obviously I'm either doing something wrong or are barking up the wrong tree entirely)